# Como ordenar la salida del administrador de django

Tags: django-admin

Tengo que ordenar los registros que se cargan desde el administrador de django, por elemento->marca->modelo, pero me ordena por el id no por el nombre.

**models.py**

```
class ElementoModelo(models.Model):
    elemento = models.ForeignKey(Elemento)
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['elemento', 'marca', 'modelo']

def __str__(self):
    return ("%s - %s - %s"%(self.elemento, self.marca, self.modelo )).strip() or "-"
```

**admin.py**

```
class ElementoModeloAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('elemento', 'marca', 'modelo',)
```

Me podrían orientar
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría sobrescribiendo el comportamiento por defecto de la método get_queryset del `ModelAdmin`:

```
class ElementoModeloAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('elemento', 'marca', 'modelo', )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super(ElementoModeloAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).order_by('elemento', 'marca', 'modelo', )
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda :).

¡Un saludo!